# Google maps GMSMarker changes camera focus iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am having an issue that GMSMarker changes camera focus on any kind of popup alert or whenever I tap on marker and app navigates to google maps application. Following is my implementation. I add google maps container to my viewcontroller header in layoutsubviews method. No idea what's going on. Kindly help.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        if mapView == nil
        {
            let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 45.582045, longitude:74.32937, zoom: 14.0)
            mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.mapContainerView.bounds.size.width, height: self.mapContainerView.bounds.size.height), camera: camera)
            mapView.delegate = self

            do {
                // Set the map style by passing the URL of the local file.
                if let styleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "style", withExtension: "json") {
                    mapView.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(contentsOfFileURL: styleURL)
                } else {
                    NSLog("Unable to find style.json")
                }
            } catch {
                NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
            }

            self.mapContainerView.addSubview(mapView)
            mapView.settings.setAllGesturesEnabled(false)
            let marker = AppointmentMapDataManager(mapView: mapView).setAppointmentMarker()
//            let location = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: marker.position.latitude,
//                                                  longitude: marker.position.longitude,
//                                                  zoom: 14)
//            mapView.camera = location
            var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
            bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate((marker as AnyObject).position)
            let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: self.mapContainerView.frame.height/2 - 33, left: self.mapContainerView.frame.width/2 - 81, bottom: 0, right: 0))
            mapView.moveCamera(update)
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: why you are moving your GMSCamera in viewDidLayoutSubViews?

Comment: I need to focus on marker bounds.

Comment: but make it in the marker selected delegate method

Comment: which method @ReinierMelian?

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of move your camera in the viewDidLayoutSubView which is a wrong approach use didTap method of the `GMSMapViewDelegate` or if you want to do it automatically use a execute after delay

```
//method for center camera based in your own code
func centerInMarker(marker: GMSMarker) {
    var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
    bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate((marker as AnyObject).position)
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds, with: UIEdgeInsets(top: (self.mapView?.frame.height)!/2 - 33, left: (self.mapView?.frame.width)!/2 - 81, bottom: 0, right: 0))
    mapView?.moveCamera(update)
}
```

**You can use it in the delegate method**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    self.centerInMarker(marker: marker)
    return true
}
```

**Or simply when you add your marker, with delay**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
        self.centerInMarker(marker: marker)
}
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks. At first I was returning false in didTap method I changed that to true and included moveCamera statements. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should add in `viewDidLoad` method, and update `frame` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Actually marker position gets disturb on UIAlertView only.

Comment: You can see in second screenshot that it has moved to left after showing alert message.